# how do I make URI of dynamic web reference look in web.config instead of app.config?

Tags: web-services, dll, asmx, uri

I have a class library(DLL) which has a web reference, its dynamic.

I have copied the setting into the applicationSettings of the web.config but still it keeps referring to the old URI I had set during develoment.

any idea how i can make it take the URI of the web-service from the web.config?

Comment: Elaboration: It maybe just a problem of adding this config in web.config in a proper way, where do i need to add this in the  web.config?

Comment: after further research it appears I am challenged in the area of figuring out how to setup application settings.

Maybe I should close this thread and start another one, If I have multiple DLLs with their own settings, how do i consolidate all that in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that it's taking the value from app.config if you're running in a web application. You are probably seeing the default value, not the configured value in app.config.

To see this, change the value in app.config and see if the service picks it up.